# generic class dynamic initialization(with spring RestTemplate)

Tags: java, generics, dynamic, resttemplate

I am currently `common api client util` using `spring rest template`.
Our api result like following..

single result :

```
{
    "data" :  {
        "id" : "...",
        "name" : "..."
        ...
    }
}
```

multiple result :

```
{
    "data" :  {
        "cnt" : 30,
        "list" : [
            {
                "id" : "...",
                "name" : "..."
                ...
            },
            {
                "id" : "...",
                "name" : "..."
                ...
            },
            {
                "id" : "...",
                "name" : "..."
                ...
            }
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

And I made two common response class like following

```
public class Response<T> {
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ListResponse<T> {
    private long cnt;
    private List<T> list;

    public long getCnt() {
        return cnt;
    }
    public void setCnt(long cnt) {
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

and example of using `RestTemplate` is

```
public <T> T apiCaller(String api){
    T result= restTemplate.exchange(api, 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            new HttpEntity<>(headers), 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<T>>(){}).getBody().getData();

    return result;
}
```

and then I used,
when the result is single,

```
UserResponse user = apiRequest.<UserResponse>apiCaller("/users/1");
```

when the result is multiple,

```
ListResponse<UserResposne> users = apiRequest.<ListResponse<UserResponse>>apiCaller("/users");
```

But it also doesn't work.
it occur `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.joont.Response.ListResponse`.

So I searched so much in google, but I didn't search how...
How can I solve this problem?
and I did it wrong? is it impossible?

Comment: You can't use `ParameterizedTypeReference` with a type variable. Since generics are erased, it will store no type information, and it looks like the api just defaults to using a `LinkedHashMap` here. The fact that you're explicitly passing the type arguments does not matter. You will have to pass a `ParameterizedTypeReference` that uses a concrete type instead.

Comment: it's so sad, that's the only way..